# String handling in T sql for mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a variable

```
DECLARE url varchar(3000)
```

and incoming parameters

```
scheme VARCHAR(5),
subdomain VARCHAR(55),
domain VARCHAR(55),
tld VARCHAR(55)
```

yet when i do the following:

```
SET url = url + ltrim(rtrim(scheme)) + '://';
SET url = url + ltrim(rtrim(subdomain)) + '.';
SET url = url + ltrim(rtrim(domain));
SET url = url+ '.' + ltrim(rtrim(tld));
```

And insert to the database i get "0"

I'm a newb with sql, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: tsql is sql server, not mysql.  Which is it?

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: Sybase uses TSQL as well.

Comment: mysql, i thought it's called tsql there as well

Comment: No, MySQL hasn't given a name to it's extension of SQL - that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

Your initial url variable is `NULL`.  Think of `NULL` like you would an `undefined` value in math — when you perform any operations on an undefined value, the result is still undefined.  Similarly, if you concatenate `NULL` with a string, the result is still `NULL` (depending on the options set on the server/database/script).  Set it to an empty string to start with and it should work.

Comment: neglacted to say, i have 

SET url = '';

at the beinging